How to create outbound messages programmatically in Salesforce? (Using Tooling API)
Is there any way to create outbound message programmatically ? May be a Tooling API can do that?
I am looking for some logic or documentation which helps in creating outbound message. If someone can provide my any solution in php or node that would help.

Create as in "configure them in setup, edit 'templates'" so to speak? Or trigger sending concrete instances, with actual data merged in?
